# Proof that induced mapping in a product by a quotient is continuous

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In several topological constructions I end up passing a continuous map to the quotient. I have a theorem stating that if I have a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ and I define two compatible equivalence relations in $X,Y$ then the map: 
$$\overline{f}:X/R \to Y/R'$$ that sends $[x] \mapsto [f(x)]$ is continuous.

Now I'm presented the following situation, which in principle, does not have anything to do with the above even if we could draw a squared conmutative diagram.

Here $X = \overline{D} \times [0,1]$ and $Y = \overline{D} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ where $\overline{D} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$ is the unit disc. I have a continuous mapping between them $H$: $$H:X \times Y \to X$$

Now consider an equivalence relation that works as follows:

$p R q \iff \begin{cases} p = q & \text{or} \\ \{p,q\} \subseteq \mathbb{S}^1 \land pR_0q &  \end{cases}$

Here $\mathbb{S}_1$ is the border of the disc and $R_0$ is a non-fixed equivalence relation on the border.

Call $U = (\overline{D} \setminus \{(0,0)\})/R$. How can I reason that the mapping: $$U \times [0,1] \to U$$ that does $([(x,y)],s) \mapsto [H((x,y),s)]$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial solution if we additionally assume that the quotient map $\pi:X\to X/R$ is open. First let me rewrite everything to make it clearer (took me a while to understand what's going in your question).

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and $A\subseteq X$. Consider a continuous function

$$H:X\times Y\to A$$

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$ and consider

$$F:(X/R)\times Y\to (A/R)$$
$$F([x], s)=[H(x,s)]$$

**Lemma.** If the projection $\pi:X\to X/R$ is open and $F$ is well defined then $F$ is continuous.

*Proof.* Let $U$ be an open subset of $A/R$. Then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$. Since $H$ is continuous then $H^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X\times Y$. Consider the projection

$$\Pi:X\times Y\to X/R\times Y$$
$$\Pi(x,y)=(\pi(x), y)$$

Since the product of two open maps is open then $\Pi$ is open. Now note that

$$F^{-1}(U)=\Pi(H^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(U)))$$

and since $\Pi$ is open then so is $F^{-1}(U)$ which completes the proof. $\Box$

I don't know how to prove it without the additional assumption. My guess is that it isn't true in general.

Comment: @Rodrigo Can you explain what exactly $R_0$ is? Without some additional assumptions on $R_0$ I don't think that the projection has to be open.

Comment: in principle the $R_0$ is an unspecified...somebody told me i could take in $[0,1]$ the trivial equivalence relationship and this should work